# Logstash conditional output using environment variable not working

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, logstash

I'm using Logstash to send log data to Elasticsearch (of course), but some of my end users also want the data sent to a secondary csv file so they can do their own processing. I am trying to use an environment variable to determine if we need to output to a secondary file and if so, where that file should live.

My Logstash looks like this:

```
input {
    . . .
}
filter {
    . . .
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        . . .
    }
    if "${SECONDARY_OUTPUT_FILE:noval}" != "noval" {
        csv {   
            fields => . . .
            path => "${ SECONDARY_OUTPUT_FILE:noval}"
        }
    }
}
```

When SECONDARY_OUTPUT_FILE has a value, it works fine. When it does not, Logstash writes csv output to a file named "noval". My conclusion is that the if statement is not working correctly with the environment variable.

I'm using Logstash version 2.3.2 on a Windows 7 machine.

Any suggestions or insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually that is a very good question, there is still an ongoing enhancement opened on this topic on [github](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/5115), as mentioned by *IrlJidel* on the issue, a workaround to the issue would be:

```
mutate {
  add_field => { "[@metadata][SECONDARY_OUTPUT_FILE]" => "${SECONDARY_OUTPUT_FILE:noval}" }
}

if [@metadata][SECONDARY_OUTPUT_FILE] != "noval" {
      csv {   
        fields => . . .
        path => "${SECONDARY_OUTPUT_FILE}" 
      }
}
```

Comment: That worked. I put the mutate statement in the filter section, then referenced the metadata field in the conditional statement. I still had to used the environment variable (NOT the metadata field) for my path.

Comment: @NormanLynch Like in my edit? Strange, and you used in the path `[@metadata][SECONDARY_OUTPUT_FILE]` (without any quotes)?

Answer (score 0):

just a quick update, since Logstash 7.17 using variables in conditionals work as expected: https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/5115#issuecomment-1022123571

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31346698)